# Vue docker deployments on AWS ECS initially loads with the js and css files as html

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, docker, vue.js, amazon-ecs

I've got a Vue app running on AWS ECS Fargate. It works fine in general, the issue I'm having is just something that happens on deployments when it spins up a new task (container).

What happens is right after deployment if I hard refresh the website it loads a blank page with `syntax error unexpected token <` in the console. This error is because the css and js files eg. app.js contents are html, specifically they are the index.html file. If I hard refresh the page again, the site loads fine and the css and js files load correctly.

I haven't been able to replicate this on localhost, how I replicate it is that I deploy to ECS and then keep hard refreshing the page until it happens, sometimes it doesn't happen. I think it happens on the first second of starting up the container and then its fine after that.

My dockerfile:

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage

# Declare ARGS
ARG VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT_ARG
ARG VUE_APP_ENVIRONMENT_ARG
ARG VUE_APP_GTM_ARG
ARG VUE_APP_INTERCOM_ARG
ARG VUE_APP_LOAD_FULL_STORY_ARG
ARG VUE_APP_LOAD_HOTJAR_ARG
ARG VUE_APP_ONCE_OFF_PRICE_ARG
ARG VUE_APP_PEACH_PAYMENTS_BASE_URL_ARG
ARG VUE_APP_SENTRY_DSN_ARG
ARG VUE_APP_STRIKETHROUGH_ONCE_OFF_PRICE_ARG
ARG VUE_APP_SUBSCRIPTION_PRICE_ARG

# Set ENV variables
ENV VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT=$VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT_ARG
ENV VUE_APP_ENVIRONMENT=$VUE_APP_ENVIRONMENT_ARG
ENV VUE_APP_GTM=$VUE_APP_GTM_ARG
ENV VUE_APP_INTERCOM=$VUE_APP_INTERCOM_ARG
ENV VUE_APP_LOAD_FULL_STORY=$VUE_APP_LOAD_FULL_STORY_ARG
ENV VUE_APP_LOAD_HOTJAR=$VUE_APP_LOAD_HOTJAR_ARG
ENV VUE_APP_ONCE_OFF_PRICE=$VUE_APP_ONCE_OFF_PRICE_ARG
ENV VUE_APP_PEACH_PAYMENTS_BASE_URL=$VUE_APP_PEACH_PAYMENTS_BASE_URL_ARG
ENV VUE_APP_SENTRY_DSN=$VUE_APP_SENTRY_DSN_ARG
ENV VUE_APP_STRIKETHROUGH_ONCE_OFF_PRICE=$VUE_APP_STRIKETHROUGH_ONCE_OFF_PRICE_ARG
ENV VUE_APP_SUBSCRIPTION_PRICE=$VUE_APP_SUBSCRIPTION_PRICE_ARG

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

The image below is where the error is coming from, the app.js file contains html (the index.html file specifically). When I refresh the page again the js files contain js as expected. This is just how it looks on the odd occasion I can catch the error after a deployment. It also sometimes happens on the .css files and not just the .js files.
[image: sources when error shows]

I've been struggling with this for a couple days now and can't figure it out. I tried adding `<base href="/" />` to the head of the index.html file as suggested to similar problems online, but it didn't work, that solution seemed more for people who were having this error consistently and not just for a second after deployments.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? Or how I can get around it with giving the task in ECS more time to load up correctly, if that is the problem? I have a loadbalancer that does health checks and only sends users to the server if it gives a 200 status, but the blank page with the syntax error returns a 200 status so the loadbalancer thinks its healthy.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit:
My nginx.conf for more info

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

  # enable gzip compression
  gzip on;
  gzip_min_length  1000;
  gzip_types    text/plain text/xml text/css application/javascript application/json;
  # end gzip configuration
}
```

Comment: See possible answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77252771/1704845